# Java Command Objects vs. Method

Tags: java, api-design, garbage, command-pattern

I am thinking about an API for a module that I am just writing. I have a bunch of commands where each one has different parameters, modes and so on. For example, i can apply a command in different Address modes (`UNADDRESSED, ADDRESSED, SELECTED, ...`)
And depending on this, we may need an address in the parameters or not.

I am wondering how to expose such an API as a Java Interface.
In the end, these commands trigger some hardware that is connected via ethernet or so.

Currently, I have 2 Ideas:

1. Command Objects: `void doA(CommandA c)` where `CommandA` holds all parameters/mode information as fields. I will now have to check in `doA` if it is a valid combination of parameters.
2. Method overload: for each combination of valid parameters, there is one method, e.g. `doA_VariantI(int param1, byte[] param2, byte[] payload, ....)` and `doA_VariantII(int param1, byte[] payload, ...)`

Method overloading is probably the safest to exclude invalid parameter combinations. But I will have to create 6-7 overloads per command (which I would like to avoid). Benefit would be that all parameters are on the stack, whereas command objects would create a ton of garbage.

I am wondering if anyone can share some experience about this. Is garbage actually a thing to worry about?

Comment: "Benefit would be that all parameters are on the stack, whereas command objects would create a ton of garbage." Well, only the `int`s and the _references_ to the `byte[]`s would be on the stack. The `byte[]`s themselves would still need to be garbage collected.

Comment: uh yes, i forgot to mention that the `byte[]` are actually pre-allocated buffers.
so `byte[] payload` actually means `byte[] buf, int offset, int length`